# How to implement a process that receives two messages and adds the two numbers together in Erlang?

Tags: process, erlang, message-queue

The process `adder2`, as implemented in Erlang, has the signature:
`adder2 (In0, In1, Kill, Out) ->`
...

The three messages that can be sent to this process are as indicated in the
diagram: `{In0, Msg}`, `{In1, Msg}` and `{Kill}`, where `In0`, `In1`
and `Kill` are provided in the function’s arguments and identify the type of
message.

The process itself waits for both the input messages, where `Msg` represents
an integer value which is communicated. Once both inputs have been
received, it outputs the sum of these to the process identified as `Out`.

At any
time whilst waiting for the inputs it may be sent a `Kill` message to which it
should respond by terminating normally.

Provide an implementation of this process using the signature given above.

I understand that there needs to be a receive expression for `In0`, `In1` and `Kill` messages. However I do not know the correct syntax to allow the messages to be received in any order, can anyone assist me with this?

I am also unsure of the correct syntax for adding the two values together.

Outputting them would require them to be assigned to a result value, and sent to the Out process, such as `Out ! Result`.

Answer (score 2):

First, all variables start with an uppercase so Erlangers would read `{In0, Msg}` as a tuple where both elements are variable. If you mean message with first element of fixed value you should write `{in0, Msg}` or `{'In0', Msg}` where the first element is an atom `'in0'` or `'In0'`. There can be variant of your `adder2` with configurable the first element of the message but it will be more complicated. So if we expect messages `{in0, Msg}`, `{in1, Msg}` and `kill` (It doesn't have to be a one-element tuple.) the solution can be:

```
-module(adder2).

-export([start/1]).

start(Out) ->
    spawn(fun() -> adder2(Out) end).

adder2(Out) ->
    adder2(undefined, undefined, Out).

adder2(undefined, In1, Out) ->
    wait(undefined, In1, Out);
adder2(In0, undefined, Out) ->
    wait(In0, undefined, Out);
adder2(In0, In1, Out) ->
    Out ! In0 + In1,
    adder2(Out).

wait(In0, In1, Out) ->
    receive
        {in0, Msg} when is_integer(Msg) ->
            adder2(Msg, In1, Out);
        {in1, Msg} when is_integer(Msg) ->
            adder2(In0, Msg, Out);
        kill ->
            ok; % last in a chain of tail recursive functions so exit normal
        Msg ->
            io:format("~p: Unknown message: ~p~n", [self(), Msg]),
            adder2(In0, In1, Out)
    end.
```

Shell session example:

```
1> c(adder2).
{ok,adder2}
2> P = adder2:start(self()).
<0.43.0>
3> link(P).
true
4> process_flag(trap_exit, true).
false
5> P ! {foo, bar}.
<0.43.0>: Unknown message: {foo,bar}
{foo,bar}
6> P ! {in0, 2.3}.
<0.43.0>: Unknown message: {in0,2.3}
{in0,2.3}
7> P ! {in0, 2}.
{in0,2}
8> P ! {in1, 3}.
{in1,3}
9> flush().
Shell got 5
ok
10> P ! {in1, 2}.
{in0,2}
11> P ! {in1, 3}.  % rewrite previous value in wait/3
{in0,3}
12> P ! {in0, 4}.
{in1,4}
13> flush().     
Shell got 7
ok
14> P ! {in1, 3}.
{in1,3}
15> P ! kill.    
kill
16> flush().     
Shell got {'EXIT',<0.43.0>,normal}
ok
```